# Limit of a sum with constant

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$$\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{i^2}$$ is the given sequence. I know that sums of converging sequences are convergent also, so $\dfrac{1}{i^2}=0$ and thus the sum is also convergent. I also know that products of convergent sequences are also convergent, if both converge. $\dfrac{1}{n}=0$ so I have $0*0=0$ which shows that the sequence given above is convergent and its limit is $0$.

Correct or horribly wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrong, not horribly wrong,

The sum of a *fixed* number of convergent sequences is convergent, but in your case you have that $n$ above the sum sign. Using the integral test (for instance), you can prove that the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{i^2}$ converges. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$, the limit of your sequence is indeed $0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$0\le \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{i^2}\le \frac 1n\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

then by squeeze theorem

$$ \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{i^2}\to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

You have two sequences.

One is the sequence $$\frac {1}{n}$$ and the other one is $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{i^2}$$

The first one approaches $0$ and the second on approaches $ \frac {\pi ^2 }{6}$

Thus the product $$\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{i^2}$$ will approach $0\times \frac {\pi ^2 }{6} =0$

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying. So in the sum, if I replace the n with $\infty$ it will approach $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$? Is there a "for dummies" proof of this?

Comment: Yes, there are different proofs for the series converging to  $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$. You may find a down to earth one on you tube search for zeta function..